# Access 2010 SQL Update Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery

I need to update every row in one table, with the help with two subqueries...

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.ColumnToUpdate = 
((SELECT 10000 / DCount("ID","MyTable")) *  DCount("ID","MyTable","ID<="& MyTable.ID))
```

But this doesn't work, access complanis about an error in the first subquery...

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the division statement need to be wrapped in parenthesis? ie (10000 / DCount("ID,"MyTable")

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the SELECT statement in the first piece.  Try this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.ColumnToUpdate = 
((10000 / DCount("ID","MyTable")) *  DCount("ID","MyTable","ID<="& MyTable.ID))
```